# INSERT INTO two tables at one query

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I insert values into two tables at once?
if it not successful, both table should rollback.

I am using SQL server and the query passe throw C# code.

Comment: Why can't you use two insert statements? Unless you use an `OUTPUT` clause or a trigger, an `INSERT` statement can only affect a single table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either run the two queries as one statement

```
insert into table1 (...) values (...); insert into table2 (...) values (...)
```

or write a trigger to do the second INSERT.

Comment: Yes, this is true:

insert into table1 (...) values (...); insert into table2 (...) values (...)

but it should be in one transaction. because if the first insertion failed the second should not executed

Answer (score 4):

I would typically write a stored procedure to take in all of the values you want to write out, then call a series of `INSERT INTO` statements wrapped in a transaction.

If you provide more information, such as table structure and sample data, we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

get ans here of ur question

[SQL Server: Is it possible to insert into two tables at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time)

[How can I INSERT data into two tables simultaneously in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712678/how-can-i-insert-data-into-two-tables-simultaneously-in-sql-server)