# How do I insert into two tables all at once in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I INSERT data into two tables simultaneously in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712678/how-can-i-insert-data-into-two-tables-simultaneously-in-sql-server)

Doing a project for school so any help would be great thank you!

I have two tables - how do I insert into two tables? So both tables are linked.

First table is called `Customer` with primary key called `CID` that auto increments

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [CID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [MiddleName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [varchar](12) NOT NULL        
 CONSTRAINT [PK__CInforma__C1F8DC5968DD69DC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
```

And a second table called `Employment` that has a foreign key linked to the parent table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employment](
    [EID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Employer] [varchar](255) NOT NULL, 
    [Occupation] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Income] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [WPhone] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Employme__C190170BC7827524] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
```

Comment: You need to set SCOPE_IDENTITY to save the PK recently inserted and use it as FK on the next statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @NewID INT

INSERT INTO Customer(LastName,FirstName,......) VALUES(Value1, Value2, .....)

SELECT @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Employment(CID,Employer,.....) VALUES(@NewID, ValueA,..........)
```

**[SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx):** Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.