# INSERT same GUID into two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, output

I've searched for a solution to this, and found several examples, but none have been exactly right for my scenario.

I've got a [source] table, and two destination tables [table1] and [table2]. [table1] and [table2] both have an Id column (UniqueIdentifier). All columns in [table1] have default values, including the UniqueIdentifier.

[table1] is a parent to [table2], and contains date-time data to track when records were inserted, modified, deleted. [table2] is a detail table, describing records in [table1].

I need to SELECT all from [source], and INSERT into [table1] and [table2], retaining Id generating during [table1] insert, so I can insert this same Id into [table2] along with the data selected from [source].

```
[source]
col1, col2, col3, col4 <------This data needs to be inserted into [table2]

[table1]
Id*, date-created, date-modified, to-date <-------these all have default values

[table2]
Id*, name, description, category <-------Id generated in [table1] needs to match here
```

Hopefully I made this clear. Let me know if you need more details. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42648/1583

Comment: It seems like you need to create a Foreign Key in the second table, linked to that GUID in the first (master) table

Comment: The Foreign Key exists already, but I'm still not sure how the SELECT | INSERT would be implemented. Would you happen to have an example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve my problem after reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712735/2370655

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Import_ManagedEntity_Insert 
@TypeId int,
@CategoryId int

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE INTO ManagedEntityDetail AS med
USING z_test AS source_table
ON 1=0
WHEN not matched THEN INSERT (Id, QualifiedName, DisplayName, Description, CategoryId)
VALUES (newid(), source_table.Url, source_table.Name, source_table.Description, @categoryid)
OUTPUT inserted.id, @typeid, getutcdate(), getutcdate(), 'system', null
INTO ManagedEntity;

END
GO
```

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: There's also a [question dedicated to the technique itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id "Using merge..output to get mapping between source.id and target.id").

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the t-sql `OUPUT` clause to accomplish this.  The difficult part will be relating the newly inserted table1 record back to the source so you can insert into table2.  It depends if you are doing this one record at a time or by batch.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: I played around with OUTPUT for a while, using several different examples and after reading the MSDN article. I must be completely missing the boat on how to use OUTPUT - completely unsuccessful. Can you provide an example that solves my problem?