# Insert multiple parent child records into SQL Server 2008 in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two tables `Portfolio` and `Trades`. Once the portfolio data has been inserted, using that Id, I insert the trades details into the `Trades` table.

I will get multiple portfolio in a single request, for example, if I get two portfolio P1 and P2, I need to insert two records into the `Portfolio` table, and the corresponding trades details into the `Trades` table once for every portfolio.

How to pass this entire data in a single stored procedure call in order to maintain the transaction?

Comment: Please add the details: Tables, data, expected results and what you have done so far

Comment: The portfolio table is having the columns ID, PortfolioName, CreatedBy and CreatedOn and the Trades table is having the columns PortfolioID (reference from Portfolio table ID), Ticker, No of Shares, Action. The data is P1, Vijay, 21-Jun-2015

Comment: The portfolio table is having the columns ID, PortfolioName, CreatedBy and CreatedOn and the Trades table is having the columns PortfolioID (reference from Portfolio table ID), Ticker, No of Shares, Action. Portfolio record 1:  P1, Vijay, 21-Jun-2015 Trades for records 1: 1, MSFT, 50, Buy ; 1, IBM, 75, Sell. Portfolio Record 2: P2, Suresh, 21-Jun-2015 Trades for Records 2: 2, YAHOO, 30, Update; 2, Goog, 40, Buy. Currently, I am passing the two data table to the stored procedure one for Portfolio and one for Trades and calling the stored procedure for every portfolio.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the entire portfolio and trades data to the stored procedure and iterate every portfolio and manipulate those records in the sql server itself without calling the stored procedure multiple time for every portfolio.

Comment: Depending on your client, you might be able to use table valued parameters to pass the data to the stored procedure.

Comment: Why not enable transactions, call `begin transaction` and `commit` around the Stored Procedure calls?

Comment: Is there any way to pass the entire data in a single call to stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with sql server 2008, you can use [table valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(SQL.100).aspx)s to pass a table structured data in a single call to a stored procedure.
However, Not every client supports this. It's easy to use with .Net, but I doubt it's possible with VBScript, for instance.

In order to use a table valued parameter you must first create a user defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE UDT_Portfolio As Table
(
    Portfolio_Id int,
    Portfolio_Name varchar(10),
    .....
)
```

in your case, since you want to pass 2 tables, you need 2 types:

```
CREATE TYPE UDT_Trades As Table
(
    Trade_Id int,
    Trade_Portfolio_Id int,
    Trade_Name varchar(10),
    ....
)
```

Now, to use them in a stored procedure is very easy:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_InsertPortfoliosAndTrades
(
     @Portfolio UDT_Portfolio readonly, -- Note: Readonly is a must
     @Trade UDT_Trades readonly
)
AS

-- stored procedure logic here
```

**Note #1:**: Table valued parameters are readonly. meaning you can't use update, insert or delete statements on them. 
However, you can declare a table valued *variable* inside a stored procedure and use insert, update, and deletes on that.

**Note #2:** If your portfolio id is an identity column, then when inserting the data to the portfolio table you will need to use an [`output`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.100).aspx) clause to get the new id values.

Comment: Currently, I am doing in the way you have mentioned. My requirement is to process multiple portfolio at the same time. I am calling the stored procedure once for every portfolio. Is there any way to pass all the portfolios in a single call.

Comment: If you are using a table valued parameter you can fill it with how many rows you want... what is the problem?

Comment: How will you maintain the relationship in the table valued parameter between the portfolio and trades table, if I pass the multiple portfolio and multiple trades for every portfolio. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Look [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73635/insert-into-select-into-multiple-related-tables-using-insert-identity) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712678/how-can-i-insert-data-into-two-tables-simultaneously-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Thanks again :)