# Insert data into multiple tables from 1 source

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables which I want to combine into 2 new ones. Current model:

Table X

`Id     Description
 A      Entry 1X
 B      Entry 2X
 C      Entry 3X`

Table Y

`Id     Description
 1      1Y
 2      2Y
 3      3Y`

And now there's a intermediate table linking those 2 together in several combinations:

Table Z

`IdX     IdY     Number1     Number2
 A       1       1000        2000
 A       2        300         400
 A       3        790        7900
 B       1         99         999
 C       1       5000         500
 C       3        250         2500`

What I want to do is insert this data into 2 tables. One will be an intermediate again, the other containing all combinations of IdX and IdY (table 'code'). The intermediate will contain 2 foreign keys which are also combined PK's. One to employee and one to table 'code'). Besides these 2 FK's this table will contain the numbers of table Z. Example of both new tables:

Table code

`Id     Description
 1     Entry 1X - 1Y
 2     Entry 1X - 2Y
 3     Entry 1X - 3Y`

Table intermediate

`IdEmployee     IdCode      Number1     Number2
 Petersen       1           1000        2000
 Petersen       3            790        7900
 Benjamin       1           1000        2000
 Benjamin       2            300         400

 Benjamin       3            790        7900`

So I have searched for this specific question but couldn't find exactly the same problem. Closest I found was: [How can I INSERT data into two tables simultaneously in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712678/how-can-i-insert-data-into-two-tables-simultaneously-in-sql-server)

But this is about 1 old record that is inserted into 2 new tables with 1 record in each new table. What I am doing is inserting a new record into table 'code' for each combination of X and Y found in the old intermediate table. Then I want to insert new records into the new intermediate table linking all new records in 'code' to all existing records in table Employee.

What I got to so far:

```
insert into code (Id, Column1, Column2, Description)
OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO intermediate (codeId, EmployeeId, Z.Number1, Z.Number2)
select id,0,1,CONCAT(x.Description,' - ',y.Descritpion)
from dba.Z
left outer join dba.X as x on x.Id = IdX
left outer join dba.Y as y on y.Id = IdY
```

But this won't work cause I haven't got a set of employees. Can anyone help me with a solution? Or do I really need to use a cursor?

Note: I have changed my source to anonymous data.

Comment: How do you know which employee to combine with which records? I see no employee referenced in any of X, Y, or Z.

Comment: All employees need to be combined with all codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do that in steps. First create your table `code` with a reference to the existing tables: `code(id, description, idx, idy)`.

Then insert records:

```
insert into code (idx, idy, description)
select x.id, y.id, x.description + ' - ' + y.description
from x
cross join y;
```

then create the table `intermediate` and fill it:

```
insert into intermediate (idcode, number1, number2, idemployee)
select code.id, z.number1, z.number2, employees.id
from code
join z on z.idx = code.idx and z.idy = code.idy
cross join employees;
```

Then you can remove `idx` and `idy` from table `code` and drop your old tables.

Comment: Thanks, pretty much what I had in mind if there wasn't a smarter way to do it.