# How to insert multiple records on Transaction

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express

I have a question about SQL Server transactions

I want to insert datas into Table_A and Table_B.
Table_B has a Table_A's key.
Table_B's records size (has Table_A's key) is dynamic.

**[Table_A]**
  id: ,
  title:

**[Table_B]**
id: ,
tableA_id:,
title:

My code work only the case insert data is static size.
like this

```
var tableBtitles = ['abc','def','ghi'] //this size is dynamic
const transaction = new sql.Transaction()
  transaction.begin(err => {

  const request = new sql.Request(transaction)
  request.query("insert into tableA (title) output Inseted.Id values('a')" , (err, result) => {
    const request = new sql.Request(transaction)
    request.input('tableA_id',mssql.NVarChar,
      result['recordset'][0]['id']);  
    request.input('title1',mssql.NVarChar,
      tableBtitles[0]); 
    request.input('title2',mssql.NVarChar,
      tableBtitles[1]); 
    request.input('title3',mssql.NVarChar,
      tableBtitles[2]); 
    request.query('insert into tableB (tableA_id,title) values(@tableA_id,@title1),(@tableA_id,@title2),(@tableA_id,@title2)), (err, result) => {
      transaction.commit(err => {

      })
  })
})
```

Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table VALUES ('value1','value2', int)`

Comment: sorry,this question is not about SQL.

Comment: @dbajtr updated my post.sorry for confusing you.

Comment: This *is* a SQL question as much as it is a *Javascript* question.  It doesn't matter where the database is hosted. The product and language are the same. Although this looks more like a 'How do I write this in Javascript` question. If you want to use SQL statements, you'll have to use a loop to INSERT the parent records, retrieve the new ID and then insert the child records

Comment: To avoid all those round trips you can *batch* the items and generate a multi-row INSERT, eg `INSERT INTO...  OUTPUT Inserted.Title, Inserted.ID VALUES ('a'), ('B'),...`. You need to return the title and ID otherwise you won't know which ID matches which title

Comment: *You can avoid this though* if you use a different strategy to generate new IDs on the client. Once you have that, you can just insert the rows, even using `bulk`.

Answer (score 1):

try this syntax

```
insert into [Table_A] ([data]) 
output inserted.id, inserted.data into [Table_B]
```

--check here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712735/8543453